# How to wait until mqueue creation is available?

Tags: c++, c, linux, unix, mqueue

I have to write program that heavily uses queues from mqueue.h. The problem is it can easily reach `/proc/sys/fs/mqueue/queues_max` limit which I cannot change. Is it possible to wait until creation of new queue is available without hard spinning? I mean something like

```
do {
    desc = mq_open(name, O_CREAT | O_RDONLY, 0666, NULL);
    if(errno == 24) // "Too many open files"
        mq_wait_for_free(); // I ask for this
    else {
        perror("creation of mqueue");
        exit(-1);
    }
} while (desc < 0);
```

Comment: I have to ask, why do you use so many queues?  Suspect XY problem:(

Comment: If you HAVE to do this, just use a semaphore, initialized to queues_max.  An obvious solution that will work, one that would be immediately clear to anyone familiar with OS synchro objects, which is why I suspect that your design is umm... 'less than optimal':(

Comment: My first idea is to check for changes in '/dev/mqueue/'. You can use [inotify](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/04/inotify-c-program-example/) to wait till changes in folder and then try again mq_opening.

Comment: in [man-page for inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html) you have a better example and i would recommend first look there.

Comment: @MartinJames not only "your" processes can open queues, so adding semaphore won't change anything. Especially user can always call in terminal `rm /dev/mqueue/mq_name` without any semaphore releasing

Comment: @MartinJames For my college project (hate from first sight).